# Web App tweak in 14.04?

Tags: unity, firefox, 14.04

After upgrading to 14.04, web apps now open in a Firefox window without the FF menus or navigation bar, or option to add tabs.  I liked it better with those. A major annoyance is the inability to copy/paste between normal FF windows and the web apps.  I get that web apps are to treat these like a standalone program, but is there a way I can tweak mine to open in a normal FF windows with menu, nav, and tabs?

Comment: I'm too suffer from this problem. I use Lastpass, so I never remember any password. Without copy-paste, now unity web app is useless for me.